# how to write external files from Teradata SP?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working on a Oracle to TD migration project. In that, I have to write a external file from Teradata SP which is called from a bteq (through ksh in unix). I thought of writing a file from bteq itself, but the problem is, I am having lot variables which i cant use in bteq. Please help me here.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

Written correctly your KSH script calling BTEQ can incorporate UNIX environmental variables. Below is a simple example of how I have done it in the past. I believe you may be able to extend the example to even include resolving environment variables within SQL statements that are to be executed.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
###############################################################################
SHELL_NAME=`basename $0`
PRG_NAME=`basename ${SHELL_NAME} .ksh`
BTQLOG=${PRG_NAME}.log
BTQOUT=${PRG_NAME}.out
LOGON=${PRG_NAME}.con
#
CREATEUS='create_user.spl'
#
if [[ ! -e ${CREATEUS} ]]; then 
   echo "FAILED: Missing ${CREATEUS} - Place ${CREATEUS} in same location as ${SHELL_NAME}"
   return 1
fi 
#
bteq <<EOBTQ > ${BTQLOG} 2>&1
.run file=${LOGON};

.SET WIDTH 255;
/*
|| CREATE_USER Stored Procedure - This procedure is intended to be used by the individual SECADMIN user(s) to create databases
*/

.LABEL CREATE_USER_PROC

SELECT 'X' (TITLE '')
  FROM DBC.TablesV
 WHERE DatabaseName = 'SECADMIN'
   AND TableName    = 'CREATE_USER'
   --AND TableKind    = 'P'
;

.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT > 0 THEN .GOTO CREATE_ROLE_PROC;

.IF ERRORCODE > 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

.COMPILE FILE = '${CREATEUS}';

.IF ERRORCODE > 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;
.LABEL EXIT_BTEQ

.QUIT ERRORLEVEL;

EOBTQ
#
STATUS=$?
#
if (( ${STATUS} != 0))
then 
   echo "FAILED: ${SHELL_NAME} completed with non-zero returne code  - Check ${BTQLOG} for details"
else 
   echo "SUCCSSS: ${SHELL_NAME} - Check ${BTQLOG} for details"
fi
#
return ${STATUS}
```